# How to enter the text in the 'textarea' of a table using Laravel Dusk or WebDriverBy?

Tags: laravel, xpath, types, selector, laravel-dusk

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">
           <input type="text" class="form-control">
         </th>

         <th scope="row">
             <textarea rows="8" class="form-control"></textarea>
         </th>
         <th scope="row"></th>
         </tr> 
        <tr>  </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

If I want to add the text in the textarea using laravel dusk in the above textarea how can I use the `type()` method here, using xpath to get the selector.

my xpath for the element is:
`$selector = "//div[@id='__BVID__34']/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/th[1]/input";`

Could anyone suggest me how to use the this selector inside the type method: 
`$browser->type('$selector', 'text-to-type');`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/dusk#using-forms), you're supposed to use a CSS selector. In your case (try to make it shorter or use [shorthand selectors](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/dusk#shorthand-selectors)) :

```
div#__BVID__34 > div > div:nth-of-type(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) > th:nth-of-type(1) > input
```

Then you can use one of the following methods to type your data :

```
$browser->type('CSSselector', 'yourtext');
$browser->keys('CSSselector', 'yourtext');
```